# In Android i want to run countdown timer who can run in background also

Tags: android, multithreading, timer, handler, countdowntimer

Hi Friends am developing one app in which my requirement is to run the timer in background also
like popular candy crush game 
my actual requirement is like when i open my app first time in a day i want to start countdown timer 24:00:00
after some time suppose i leave my application and open other application during same time my countdown timer must be running it will never be pause or it will never be stop

i visit almost 8,9 tutorial but am not getting exact result please help me out what kind of class may i use or any tutorial link please thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options: `Service` and storing time of app launching. `Service` could be killed by system at any time, so you have to save time on `onDestroy` method and then when system will relaunch your `Service` system will call `onCreate` method where you need to restore timer. The second method is easier. You could store current time on starting your app and then just check differences. Sample:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    final SharedPreferences appPrefs = getSharedPreferences("appPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    final long launchTime = appPrefs.getLong("launchTime", 0);
    final long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    if(launchTime == 0){
        //first launch
        appPrefs.edit().putLong("launchTime", currentTime);
    }else{
        long diff = currentTime - launchTime;
        long minutesPassed = diff / 1000 / 60;

        if(24 * 60 <= minutesPassed){
            //24 hours passed since app launching
        }else{
            //24 hours didn't passed since app launching
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks @fox in socks 
let me check this solution but i have one doubt
suppose this scenario is valid timer is coundwoning from 24 to 0 and i changed device time then is this scenario works??

Comment: @VikrantAlekar `System.currentTimeMillis` returns time according to the system time so if user change system time this method will return appropriate time. Using `Service` you need the start point(`System.currentTimeMillis`) also. If you want completely  independent time measuring you need to use separate server(e.g. machine where time is unchangeable).